# Не работает кнопка формы обратной связи

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, form

Всем привет!
Проблема с формой обратной связи- кнопка отправить не реагирует после посадки на ворпресс, до этого сайт работал без движка, с кнопкой все было ок
Пробовала по всякому менять путь к файлу form-submit.php, подозреваю, что проблема в этом, но при любом пути результата нет
Подскажите, в чем на самом деле проблема и как ее решить
Заранее спасибо!
Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/form-submit.php" name="form-request" id="form-request-6" class="" data-delay="0">
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="target_6" />
<div class="modal-body "  style="display: flex;">
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 field field-text required">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-letters" name="name" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя*" />
<div class="error-text">Поле обязательное для заполнения</div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 field field-text required">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-mask__phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Ваш телефон*" />
<div class="error-text">Поле обязательное для заполнения</div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 field field-buttons">
<button class="btn form-button-submit" type="submit" style="font-size: 18px;">Отправить заявку</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Скрипт:

```
    $('.input-mask__phone').inputmask("mask", {
        "mask": "+7 (999)-999-99-99",
    });
    $('input[type="text"].input-letters').keypress(function(){
        let that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            let res = /[^a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]/g.exec(that.value);
            that.value = that.value.replace(res, '');
        }, 0);
    });
    $('.content-form .field.required input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()) $(this).closest('.field').addClass('error');
        else $(this).closest('.field').removeClass('error');
    });
    $('.content-form button.form-button-submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        let isError = false;
        let form = $(this).closest('form');
        form.find('.field').removeClass('error');
        form.find('.field.field-text.required').each(function(index, item){
            let itemInput = $(item).find('input[type="text"]');
            if (!itemInput.val()){
                $(item).addClass('error');
                isError = true;
            }
            else $(item).removeClass('error');
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (!isError){
                let formSerializeData = form.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url:  '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/form-submit.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: formSerializeData,
                    success: function(response){
                        if (response === 'ok'){
                            $('#modal_form_submit').modal('show');
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
        }, 300);
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libs/PHPMailer/functions.inc.php');
$data = $_POST;
$to_mail = 'daria@nomoko.ru';

if ($data['target'] == 'target_1'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: Автономная газификация';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_2'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: Технические газы';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_3'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: АГЗС, Корпоративное обслуживание';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_4'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: АГЗС, Программа лояльности';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_5'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: Заправка газгольдеров';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Адрес: '.$data['address'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_6'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: Установка ГБО';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_7'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: Тюнинг ГБО';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}
elseif ($data['target'] == 'target_8'){
    $subject = 'Сайт LPG: Регистрация ГБО';
    $body = 'Свяжитесь с клиентом!<br />Имя: '.$data['name'].'<br />Телефон: '.$data['phone'];
}

if (!empty($subject) && !empty($body)){
    $result = smtpmail($to_mail, $subject, $body);
}
else {
    $result = false;
}

if ($result === true) echo 'ok';
```

Comment: Советую вам вместо кастомной формы установить плагин cf7 или что-то в этом роде и сделать форму через это плагин

Comment: Да и код - сплошная дыра в плане безопасности. Хотите делать кастомные формы - учите ajax в WordPress: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html